# Finding places of interest within a circle

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

I'm planning to build an android application that draws a circle around a certain point on the map and finds all the points of interests (e.g., hotels) inside that circle.

I created the circle in my app by using the Google Maps Android API via

```
 GoogleMap map;
 Circle circle = map.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
 .center(new LatLng(MY_LAT, MY_LONG))
 .radius(MY_RADIUS)
 .strokeColor(Color.RED)
 .fillColor(Color.BLUE));
```

I also know that I can find places of interest using the Google Places API.

As far as I know, the [PlacePicker](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/placepicker) is used for searching places of interests.

Upon further research, I realized I could actually set `LatLng` bounds for the PlacePicker using [LatLngBounds](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLngBounds.html) and the `setLatLngBounds()` method. The method accepts a North-East corner and a South-West corner, but how do I determine them?

My question is this - How can I get the PlacePicker to scan all the places of interests inside the given circle?

One possible workaround I thought of was this:

1) Use [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15319431/how-to-convert-a-latlng-and-a-radius-to-a-latlngbounds-in-android-google-maps-ap) to obtain a set of NE and SW points

2) Add these as the parameters to the `setLatLngBounds()` methods

3) Use the PlacePicker

Is this the appropriate way? Or is there any shorter workaround?

Comment: Welcome back ! For PlacePicker see my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34416817/how-to-implement-placeautocompletefragment-and-placeautocompleteactivity-to-get) and for finds all the points of interests inside that circle see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16082622/check-if-marker-is-inside-circle-radius)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to use

```
StringBuilder googlePlacesUrl = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
                googlePlacesUrl.append("location=" + latLng.latitude + "," + latLng.longitude);
                googlePlacesUrl.append("&radius=" + 3);
                googlePlacesUrl.append("&types=" + type);
                googlePlacesUrl.append("&sensor=true");
                googlePlacesUrl.append("&key=" + "server key from google console");
```

Just use type as hotels,etcs and radius may be depends on your need.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try and implement it and inform you of the updates! :)